# Easily position image with double-height than other images

Tags: html, css

I want to make a page with 8 images like this:

```
img1 img2 img3
img4 img5 img8
img6 img7 img8
```

As you can see "img8" is double as tall as all the other images.

How do I do this in css?

Comment: There are a few different ways it can be done. Do you have some specific code you are working with?

Comment: There's a JQuery plugin called Masonry that may be of interest to you, it does this dynamically and automatically for you. This is useful if your images are likely to change over time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just basic floats:

```
.wrap {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.small {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;

    float: left;
}

.big {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;

    float: right;
}
```

I assumed a HTML structure like the one below:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="small">1</div>
  <div class="small">2</div>
  <div class="small">3</div>

  <div class="small">4</div>
  <div class="small">5</div>

  <div class="big">8</div>

  <div class="small">6</div>
  <div class="small">7</div>
</div>
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Eg8un/11/**

Comment: Is the inline-block really needed when floating?

Comment: I guess not. I use it a bit too much.

Comment: Good question. I'm your +1 offsetting vote to that. Maybe they did not like your `div`s instead of `img`s in your answer (for me, the div's used to illustrate the concept are not a big deal).

Comment: Yeah, you are not exactly hurting in reputation :-)

Answer (score 2):

As Scott says, there are different ways to do this. If you images have specific width and height, then see if my example fits you:

http://jsfiddle.net/J8TLV/

Comment: Why the extra (unnecessary) div's wrapping the `img` tags in your fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Since they did the floats, I'll do the absolute positioning. *The disadvantage* is more css. ***The advantage*** is that source order can be maintained (images 1-8 are ordered so in the html). I toggled off Frexuz's jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J8TLV/3/.

I thought I would **update** on *another (related) advantage*, that the images can be positioned anywhere in the "row" and "column" grid without reordering the images themselves (as you would need to with `float`).